# How does strength of password relate to encryption?

Tags: security, pdf, encryption

I have a PDF document that is 128bit encrypted.

The user insists on a four character password which is all numeric e.g. 1558 or 6977 or 4793.

128bit encryption is strong - is this strength negated by the password weakness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strength of the encryption is different to the strength of key generation. One could implement a secure, modern key generation mechanism such as PBKDF2 as Slabks says, but use a relatively weak encryption cipher (like 128-bit RC4) compared to a stronger cipher (like 128-bit AES).

However, as Christian says, a single 4 digit PIN has a maximum of 10000 passwords which is not a lot of entropy to generate a key from. If there is some form of hash or other tamper detection, it would be relatively easy to brute force the encryption document with a dedicated, modern system. As you say, yes, the encryption strength is reduced by the password weakness.

To add to Christian's comment above, you see PINs now on some phone and tablet apps like DropBox because, as Christian says, they are being authenticated by the server and lock you out when too many incorrect PINs are entered. It is acceptable for ATM cards and these apps due to the limited input capabilities of ATMs, phones and tablets but is not an acceptable excuse for a system with a full keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

For a 4-character all-numneric password, there are 10000 passwords in total. It doesn't matter how "strong" your encryption is; brute force isn't even "brute". My pocket calculator could do that.

Note: the reason this works with ATMs or SIM-cards is because you don't get a chance to brute force. The ATM will eat your card after 3 failed attempts, a SIM card will lock up as well until you enter another 8-digit code, which will "permanently" lock up the card if you don't get it right in 10 attempts.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how it is implemented.

Ideally, the encryption key would be derived from the password, using secure schemes like PBKDFv2.  If so, a weak password would have no effect on the security of the encryption.

However, if the attacker knows that the key was derived using PBKDFv2, a weak password will be more vulnerable to brute-force / dictionary attacks used to derive the key.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if an attacker were to know that the password used to derive the key is just four digits, it greatly reduces the keyspace he'd have to try in a brute-force attack.

0000 to 9999 is just ten thousand combinations.

If it was ten case-sensitive alphanumerics, you'd have 62^10 (about 8 * 10^17) combinations. Too many to try them all.

Even if an attacker does not know about your user's "requirement", he'd probably start brute-forcing with short passwords, so he'll stumble upon a four-digit combination pretty soon, too.